# Add custom annotations to MapKit

Tags: swift

I am relatively new to Swift language. I know how to launch mapkit in my app with added annotations but I want to add a pin without the standard red pin but with a custom image that i have. Is there a simple way to make it happen? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't add any code into your question so I am giving you an example code.

Use this delegate method `viewForAnnotation` for custom pin.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
        return nil
    }

    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("pin")

    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
        pinView!.canShowCallout = true
        //Set your image here
        pinView!.image = UIImage(named: "mappin")

        var calloutButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.DetailDisclosure) as! UIButton
        pinView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = calloutButton
    }
    else {
        pinView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    return pinView
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: ok.. and then how do I add it to the mapkit? I have only used place marks for the job.

Comment: Follow this tutorial : http://www.raywenderlich.com/90971/introduction-mapkit-swift-tutorial it will help you.